# Keep observations with two or more consecutive years of data by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset consisting of directorid, match_id, and calyear. I would like to keep only observations by director_id and match_id that have at least 2 consecutive years of data. I have tried a few different ways to do this, and haven't been able to get it quite right. The few different things I have tried have also required multiple steps and weren't particularly clean.

Here is what I have:

| director_id | match_id | calyear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 282 | 1111 | 2006 |
| 282 | 1111 | 2007 |
| 356 | 2222 | 2005 |
| 356 | 2222 | 2007 |
| 600 | 3333 | 2010 |
| 600 | 3333 | 2011 |
| 600 | 3333 | 2012 |
| 600 | 3355 | 2013 |
| 600 | 3355 | 2015 |
| 600 | 3355 | 2016 |
| 753 | 4444 | 2005 |
| 753 | 4444 | 2008 |
| 753 | 4444 | 2009 |

Here is what I want:

| director_id | match_id | calyear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 282 | 1111 | 2006 |
| 282 | 1111 | 2007 |
| 600 | 3333 | 2010 |
| 600 | 3333 | 2011 |
| 600 | 3333 | 2012 |
| 600 | 3355 | 2015 |
| 600 | 3355 | 2016 |
| 753 | 4444 | 2008 |
| 753 | 4444 | 2009 |

I started by creating a variable equal to one:

```
df['tosum'] = 1
```

And then count the number of observations where the difference in calyear by group is equal to 1.

```
df['num_years'] = (
df.groupby(['directorid','match_id'])['tosum'].transform('sum').where(df.groupby(['match_id'])['calyear'].diff()==1, np.nan)
                             )
```

And then I keep all observations with 'num_years' greater than 1.

However, the first observation per director_id match_id gets set equal to NaN. In general, I think I am going about this in a convoluted way...it feels like there should be a simpler way to achieve my goal. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to groupby 'director_id', 'match_id' and then do a transform but the transform just needs to look at the difference between next element in both directions. In one direction you need to see if it equals 1 and in another -1 and then subset using the resulting True/False values.

```
df = df[
    df.groupby(["director_id", "match_id"])["calyear"].transform(
        lambda x: (x.diff().eq(1)) | (x[::-1].diff().eq(-1))
    )
]
```

print(df):

```
    director_id  match_id  calyear
0           282      1111     2006
1           282      1111     2007
4           600      3333     2010
5           600      3333     2011
6           600      3333     2012
8           600      3355     2015
9           600      3355     2016
11          753      4444     2008
12          753      4444     2009
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but here is my solution to this problem:

- use `.diff()` function to calculate the difference between rows
- use list comprehension and conversions to a set to extract the indices
- once you have the necessary indices, use the `.loc()` function to select rows.

### Code:

```
indices = list(set(sum([[i-1,i] for i,row in enumerate(df['calyear'].diff()) if row == 1], [])))
new_df = df.loc[indices]
print(new_df)
```

### Output:

[image: df]

Comment: Thank you for the response! No such thing as too late to the party!